# Why the constructor is called after a static cast?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-cast, static-cast

This is my class:

```
class AComponent : public nts::IComponent
{
public:
  AComponent(const size_t &maxInputs, const size_t &maxOutputs, const size_t &value);
  AComponent(nts::AComponent &);
  virtual ~AComponent();
  virtual nts::Tristate Compute(size_t pin_num_this = 1);
  virtual void SetLink(size_t pin_num_this,
     nts::IComponent &component,
     size_t pin_num_target);
  void setComponent(const size_t &components, nts::Tristate &state);
  virtual void Dump(void) const;
  nts::Tristate &getComponent(const size_t &pin);
protected:
  std::vector <nts::Tristate *>   _components;
  size_t                        _maxInputs;
  size_t                        _maxOutputs;
};
```

And when I try to call this line:

```
this->_components[pin_num_this] =
    &static_cast<nts::AComponent>(component).getComponent(pin_num_target);
```

I have this compilation errors that happens:

```
sources/AComponant.cpp:33:76: error: no matching function for call to ‘nts::AComponent::AComponent(nts::IComponent&)’
   this->_components[pin_num_this] = &static_cast<nts::AComponent>(component).getComponent(pin_num_target);
```

And if I implement the constructor, it goes here. Problem is, I don't want to manipulate `IComponent`, I want to manipulate `AComponent`. Have you an idea why this happens?

Edit:

`this->_components` is a vector. It's declared in the constructor this way :

```
this->_components.reserve(maxInputs + maxOutputs + 2);
```

Comment: what is type of `component`?

Comment: Please show us how `component` is declared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You will need to convert `component` to a reference type - `AComponent&` (or `&component` to `AComponent*`). You don't want to copy anything.
2. You might need `dynamic_cast` to downcast from a base class to derived class **safely**. `static_cast` is for downcasting without a check, upcasting and... well, [here's the list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast).

What you should have had:

```
dynamic_cast<nts::AComponent&>(component).getComponent(pin_num_target);
```

Read how to use [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast). There's a runtime check involved. The conversion might fail and throw `std::bad_cast` (reference type) or return `nullptr` (pointer type).

**Edit:** If you have an abstract `IComponent` and only one type derived from `IComponent`, you can be pretty sure there will be an `component` will refer to an `AComponent` object. Therefore, you can do this with `static_cast`, but the 1st point still holds.

Comment: Don't necessarily need to do a `dynamic_cast`.  `static_cast` also does correct downcasting, it just doesn't check that the object's type and the target type have any sort of runtime match...so you could cast to something your object is not.  But, for example, it's rather common to implement `polymorphic_downcast` in terms of `static_cast`, with a `dynamic_cast` happening only during debug runs to validate the cast.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) If a temporary object of type `new_type` can be declared and
>   initialized with expression, as by `new_type Temp(expression);`, **which**
>   **may involve implicit conversions, a call to the constructor of**
>   `new_type` **or a call to a user-defined conversion operator**, then
>   `static_cast<type>(expression)` computes and returns the value of that
>   temporary object.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast